# Графический интерфейс открывается не в том окне

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Всем привет! Возникла проблема при нажатии на кнопку в основном окне `tkinter`, должно открываться вторничное окно в котором будут флажки и текст, но при нажатии на кнопку создаеться пустое вторичное окно а весь графический интерфейс в основном окне, у меня `Python 3.8` работаю в `Python IDLE`

Вот мой код:

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
import datetime as dt
import os


def move():
    one = 0
    two = 0
    three = 0
    four = 0
    five = 0

    root = Tk()
    root.geometry("400x400") 


    def show():
        s = f'{var1.get()}, ' \
            f'{var2.get()}, ' \
            f'{var3.get()}, ' \
            f'{var4.get()}, ' \
            f'{var5.get()}, ' \

    def buildsettings():
        if var1.get() == True:
            one = 1
        else:
            one = 0
        if var2.get() == True:
            two = 1
        else:
            two = 0
        if var3.get() == True:
            three = 1
        else:
            three = 0
        if var4.get() == True:
            four = 1
        else:
            four = 0
        if var5.get() == True:
            five = 1
        else:
            five = 0

        print(one, two, three, four, five)
        root.destroy()
      
    frame = Frame()
    frame.pack(side=LEFT)

    var1 = BooleanVar()
    var1.set(0)
    c1 = Checkbutton(frame, text="one",
                 variable=var1,
                 onvalue=1, offvalue=0,
                 command=show)
    c1.pack(anchor=W, padx=10)

    var2 = IntVar()
    var2.set(-1)
    c2 = Checkbutton(frame, text="two",
                     variable=var2,
                     onvalue=1, offvalue=0,
                     command=show)
    c2.pack(anchor=W, padx=10)

    var3 = IntVar()
    var3.set(-1)
    c2 = Checkbutton(frame, text="three",
                     variable=var3,
                     onvalue=1, offvalue=0,
                     command=show)
    c2.pack(anchor=W, padx=10)
    
    var4 = IntVar()
    var4.set(-1)
    c2 = Checkbutton(frame, text="four",
                     variable=var4,
                     onvalue=1, offvalue=0,
                     command=show)
    c2.pack(anchor=W, padx=10)

    var5 = IntVar()
    var5.set(-1)
    c2 = Checkbutton(frame, text="five",
                     variable=var5,
                     onvalue=1, offvalue=0,
                     command=show)
    c2.pack(anchor=W, padx=10)

    l1 = Label(text="hello",
           font="Arial 8")
    l1.config(bd=20, bg='#ffaaaa')
    l1.pack()
    b = tk.Button(root, text='start', command=buildsettings,)
    b.place(x=0, y=375)


def fmok():
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.geometry("800x400")
    root.title("fmok")
    root["bg"] = "black"
    b = tk.Button(root, text='open', command=move)
    b.place(x=0, y=375)

    root.mainloop()

fmok()
```

Я уже все перепробовал, ничего не выходит( Помогите

Comment: Капец почти 3 часа прошло никто так и не ответил хотя вопрос вроди не такой уж и сложный

Comment: Здорова) Смотри, скорее всего проблема в том, что ты добавляешь все кнопки в основное окно. Первое время я тоже так вляпывался XD Ща поищу где надо заменить и отвечу тебе ;)

Comment: Такс, подскажи, пожалуйста, в какой из строк создаётся новое окно? Я слеповат чутка XD

Comment: А, всё... Ты окно второе неправильно делаешь

Comment: Ты создаёшь 2 основных окна, хотя все второстепенные окна делаются(обычно) через `Toplevel`

Comment: https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/toplevel.html

Comment: 2) Ты создаёшь `Frame`, а он у тебя никуда не прикрепляется, вот его автоматом и запихивает в основно `root`. Тебе надо в фун-ию добавления елементов передать второй `root` и вставить его так: `Frame(root)` ну или вместо root любая другая переменная(смотря как назовёшь в `def buildsettings(): `)

Comment: Ща попробую исправить твой код и скину ответом ;)

Comment: буду крайне благодарен

Comment: Такс, такой вопрос. Где должна находиться кнопка `start`? Во втором ведь окне?

Comment: во втором окне должно находиться start галочки и текст, в первом окне только кнопка open

Comment: Значит правильно понял задумку)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот, вроде как делает всё что ты хотел ;)

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
import datetime as dt
import os


def move():
    one = 0
    two = 0
    three = 0
    four = 0
    five = 0

    self = Toplevel()
    self.geometry("400x400") 


    def show():
        s = f'{var1.get()}, ' \
            f'{var2.get()}, ' \
            f'{var3.get()}, ' \
            f'{var4.get()}, ' \
            f'{var5.get()}, ' \

    def buildsettings(root):
        if var1.get() == True:
            one = 1
        else:
            one = 0
        if var2.get() == True:
            two = 1
        else:
            two = 0
        if var3.get() == True:
            three = 1
        else:
            three = 0
        if var4.get() == True:
            four = 1
        else:
            four = 0
        if var5.get() == True:
            five = 1
        else:
            five = 0

        print(one, two, three, four, five)
        root.destroy()
      
    frame = Frame(self)
    frame.pack(side=LEFT)

    var1 = BooleanVar()
    var1.set(0)
    c1 = Checkbutton(frame, text="one",
                 variable=var1,
                 onvalue=1, offvalue=0,
                 command=show)
    c1.pack(anchor=W, padx=10)

    var2 = IntVar()
    var2.set(-1)
    c2 = Checkbutton(frame, text="two",
                     variable=var2,
                     onvalue=1, offvalue=0,
                     command=show)
    c2.pack(anchor=W, padx=10)

    var3 = IntVar()
    var3.set(-1)
    c2 = Checkbutton(frame, text="three",
                     variable=var3,
                     onvalue=1, offvalue=0,
                     command=show)
    c2.pack(anchor=W, padx=10)
    
    var4 = IntVar()
    var4.set(-1)
    c2 = Checkbutton(frame, text="four",
                     variable=var4,
                     onvalue=1, offvalue=0,
                     command=show)
    c2.pack(anchor=W, padx=10)

    var5 = IntVar()
    var5.set(-1)
    c2 = Checkbutton(frame, text="five",
                     variable=var5,
                     onvalue=1, offvalue=0,
                     command=show)
    c2.pack(anchor=W, padx=10)

    l1 = Label(self, text="hello",
           font="Arial 8")
    l1.config(bd=20, bg='#ffaaaa')
    l1.pack()
    b = tk.Button(self, text='start', command=lambda: buildsettings(self))
    b.place(x=0, y=375)


def fmok():
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.geometry("800x400")
    root.title("fmok")
    root["bg"] = "black"
    b = tk.Button(root, text='open', command= lambda: move())
    b.place(x=0, y=375)

    root.mainloop()

fmok()
```

Основные ошибки:

1. Создавай другие окна через `Toplevel`
2. При создании виджетов в другом окне указывай ту переменную, в которую запихнул `Toplevel`
3. Если делаешь окна через функцию, то для каждого отдельного окна выбирай новую переменную, иначе будет считать основной `root`
4. Желательно для окон использовать Классы, и потом делать вызов класса и прописывай функции там

Comment: Ифы в `buildsettings` можно заменить на строки вида `one = int(var1.get() == True)`. Плюс нумерованные переменные можно заменить на списки, можно будет просто циклом их обрабатывать. Но это как предложение скорее. И еще, переменные one - five в move никак не изменяются - в buildsettings меняются локальные переменные с соответствующими именами, а не локальные переменные функции move. В buildsettings нужно объявить их как nonlocal.

Comment: @insolor, ну, был вечер и я старался просто чтобы его код заработал